# Unable to authorize ANY external Google Apps Script scope on any ANY file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, oauth, google-oauth

For some time now I'm unable to give any new OAuth authorization in Google Apps Scripts from my Google Account for a scope that is outside the file I'm working from (`.currentonly` works, everything else doesn't).

It asks for a Google account I want to use and after selecting the account it shows:

> This app is blocked
>
> This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.

See screenshot:
[image: This app is blocked]

The screen with the requested permissions overview is not even shown.
This happens for every new or old Spreadsheet file I try to add the permissions to. But Spreadsheets that already got the OAth before this stopped working are regularly updated with project triggers.

Here is my manifest file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly", // this works
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", // this doesn't work
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" // this also doesn't work
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Everything works when I try to do the same from a different Google account. Because of this I think it has something to do with the whole Google account settings.

I tried enabling `Less secure app access` but it didn't help. [image: Less secure app access]

Is is possible that the access from unverified 3rd-party apps is disabled in that account? How can I enable it again?