# "this app is blocked" for even the simplest Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've hunted for the answer to this, but can't find it.

I have tried to run an empty google apps script from my own google account - on which I DID turn on "less secure account access":

function myFunction() {
}

Even then, when I get the "Authorization required" pop up and try to review permissions, I get the message:

This app is blocked
This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.

I created the script using my own gmail account. I've hunted and hunted but can't find the answer. Help!

Comment: How did you search? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65399636/unable-to-authorize-any-external-google-apps-script-scope-on-any-any-file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66633659/can-not-run-trivial-app-script-bound-to-new-blank-document-get-this-app-is-bl?noredirect=1